# What determines how to treat single variable PDEs and thus their constants of integration?

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations, 3d, surfaces, constants

When solving a first-order ODE (perhaps there is also a way to extend this to a higher order ODE) for $y(x)$, it is possible to shift perspective and consider $x$ to be a function of $y$ by manipulating the differential forms.  For example, $\frac{dy}{dx} = h(y)$ can be solved as $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{h(y)}$, which may be easier.  The moral of the story, very crudely stated, seems to be that derivatives are slopes, and we can inquire about the slope of any variable with respect to any other, regardless of which variables are "actually independent" at the end of the day.

When solving a first-order PDE such as $u_t + 2xu_x = 0$, [one of the steps involves considering either $\frac{dt}{dx}$ or $\frac{dx}{dt}$](https://youtu.be/B5bdslJh5nE?t=250), even though both $x$ and $t$ are independent variables, which I'm fine with due to the above paragraph.  However, either of these derivatives are situated within a horizontal slice of $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $u$ is the dimension orthogonal to that slice.  Thus these derivatives should technically be partials, and the "ODEs" they create technically single variable PDEs, and more importantly, the constant of integration encountered when we solve either of these "ODEs" should be a function of $u$.  In this particular problem (solved using the choices made in the above timestamped video), we would get $x = K(u)e^{2t}$, which produces the correct solution $u = f(xe^{-2t})$ after dividing through by $e^{2t}$ and taking $K^{-1}$ of both sides.  In other solution methods for first-order PDEs, [constants are explicitly written as functions](https://youtu.be/6tuIA2Riq8o?t=507).

1. Does thinking about the constant of integration as a function in the context of first-order PDEs always work as it does here, or is this a coincidence?  If not, then why is it correct to use a genuine constant here instead of a function of the dimension not involved in the derivative?  Again, I'm drawing the conclusion from the first paragraph that $u$ not "actually" being an independent variable makes little difference in this context.
2. For separation of variables problems, it is similarly common to shorthand partial derivatives as ordinary derivatives once things are separated.  For example, if the PDE is $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$, and thus one of the separated equations is $Y_{yy} = \lambda Y$, we often pretend this is the same thing as $Y'' = \lambda Y$.  However, we are really solving the former, which takes place within a $2$-dimensional slice of $\mathbb{R}^3$, not the latter, which takes place within $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Thus, if we solve it by guessing the particular solution $Y = e^{\sqrt\lambda y}$ and finding the general solution via [reduction of order](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQSFW8BIrY0), it seems like we should, for both integrations that occur within reduction of order, write the constants as arbitrary functions of $x$, since integrating within a "constant $x$ slice" of $\mathbb{R}^3$ should yield that arbitrary function.  Why is it correct to use a genuine constant here?

Is there a systematic way to decide when integration constants in a three-dimensional problem should be functions, or does it come down to memorizing the decisions presented along with each solution method?

Comment: I would argue you are putting far too much emphasis on the concept of constants of integration and "generalized constants of integration" if you will. Generally what you want are definite integrals sometimes with variable limits so that these issues are just not relevant.

Comment: @Ian This feels like it would place me completely out of line with the way ODEs and PDEs are actually taught though, at least the the introductory level.  I have pulled from many sources in studying the subjects, and indefinite integration is ubiquitous; definite integration is mentioned parenthetically and VERY rarely.  Moreover, I have never had any luck getting others to answer questions related to definite integration in differential equations (i.e., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013394/definite-integration-and-initial-value-problems).

Comment: In the case of transport equations I disagree; you find the characteristics, invert the characteristics to find where a given point started out on its characteristic, and plug that in. Writing down the general solution is not really considered interesting because it doesn't show how information propagates from the initial condition in a clear way.

Comment: In the case of separation of variables I just plain don't understand what you mean. Generally the view in separation of variables is to just assemble a linear combination of solutions and then extract the coefficients by a projection procedure. The solutions themselves are what they are because of the boundary conditions, and their lack of dependence on the other variable is because the boundary conditions don't depend on the other variable either. When the boundary conditions *do* depend on the other variable the problems tend to get dramatically more difficult but are sometimes still doable.

Comment: @Ian Since you are probably much further in math than I, it's probably safe to say I will encounter the shortcut you've described (or even bypassing the whole analytic solution process in favor of numerical methods) more down the line.  All I can say is that my current experience is of being taught to solve these problems by first finding a general solution and then applying initial or boundary conditions.  As for separation of variables, I have updated that part of the question to be more accurate/detailed.

Comment: I still don't get your point with separation of variables. The point is to find a bunch of separable solutions, sum them up with coefficients by the superposition principle, and then hope you can deal with whatever forcing/initial data/etc. you have in the problem by projection. For example in $X''/X+Y''/Y=0$ (the Laplace equation scenario in rectangular coordinates), $X''/X$ and $-Y''/Y$ are indeed the same constant everywhere *for that separable solution*. The general solution is *not* separable but that part is coming up later in the derivation anyway.

Comment: As for transport equations, I was describing the way it is normally taught in my experience, not some clever shortcut that experts use and then don't teach to students. Characteristics are fundamental to how you solve those, since it's both the easiest way to do it and also provides intuition on the "propagation of information" in the equation.

Comment: @user10478 I am not sure what you are talking about when you say that definite integrals are rarely used in solving differential equations. The standard method for solving initial-condition problems, at least when equations are separable, is to separate, and apply a definite integral, with the initial condition built directly into the integral.

Comment: I think you misunderstood $\frac{dt}{dx}$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}$ in the video you mentioned in the 2nd paragraph. The derivatives are discribing a **curve** on the $x$-$t$ plane where $u=constant$. $x$ and $t$ are independent variable for the PDE, but they are dependent for **the points on the curve**. There's no one-variable PDE.

Comment: @Miscellaneous I understand these concepts, but they're somewhat metaphorical, are they not?  Speaking more precisely, the "curve" is really just a subset of the points which constitute the surface that solves the PDE.  There isn't REALLY an infinitely thin geometric object present; it's just mathematicians looking at the surface in that manner in order to conceptualize the solution process.  That's why I think partial integration is still appropriate.

Comment: @user10478 How do you discribe a curve on x-t plane? You establish the relationship between x and t for all the points on the curve, say, x = 2t. Because x and t are dependent variable for every points on the curve. If you know a point is on this curve and you know its x coordinate, can you know its t coordinate? Yes. Can you write down the relationship between x and t for all the points on x-t plane? No. If you know a point is on  x-t plane and you know its x coordinate, can you know its t coordinate? No, because they are not dependent.

Comment: @Miscellaneous Does this not just push the problem back a step?  An $x$-$t$ plane is not the full geometry of the problem.  A statement about the relation between $x$ and $t$ as though they form a curve is only correct if it is ultimately saying something correct about the surface, right?  It's just often easier to express mathematical truths about the surface using the language of curves and planes.  For example, we expect a point on a curve to have exactly two neighboring points, but we'd have to be careful about saying that a point on a planar slice of a surface has only two neighbors since

Comment: the slice itself has neighboring slices, and consequently the point of interest has many neighbors.  Ultimately, the slices are just fictions used to understand the nature of the surface.  If we want to say on philosophical grounds that all of mathematics is a fiction, then the slices are fictions within a fiction.